# SF anime about high-schooler surviving quarantine and forms society to survive

Tags: story-identification, anime

It’s an anime series with some SF or future theme. The government has the ability to close off a very large city-block with walls that can move and destroy buildings. Behind these walls, they have defenses which can kill anyone who tries to leave the quarantined area. As far as I know, there was some form of virus, but the surviving children were not contaminated.

As far as I know, it's about a high-schooler who has to survive in this quarantine and has to form a society to survive. At first, the leader wanted to be more democratic, but then his girlfriend gets killed which turns him into become a hard-line dictator. In the end (I think, not sure), they build enough resources to make an attempt to escape.

I'd like to know the title of this series. For some reason, the new *Valvrave* anime reminds me of this series.

This was a question asked many years ago on this same site and I have stumbled upon the same question myself. It is not *Guilty Crown*, nor *Betterman*.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain it's not Guilty Crown? This description matches the second part of that series for 99.9%.

Comment: Yes I am completely sure. It involves different characters and I even rewatched guilty crown recently to confirm so. It seems no one can remember what this anime is so I’m not sure.

Comment: When did you watch it? Any idea on how old the anime is? You also said it involved different characters, so any visual description could help with identifying. Did the characters have any special powers? All info is very welcome as it allows narrowing the search parameters.

Comment: "This was a question asked many years ago on this same site" could you provide the link to that question?

Comment: I figured it out thank you for trying to help, I appreciate it. I hope you guys have a wonderful day.

Comment: Mind adding it as an answer then? It could help people trying to figure it out.

Comment: The first three paragraphs of this question are a copy and paste of [another question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3739) posted on Anime & Manga SE in 2013, and the OP of that question confirmed that the answer was _Guilty Crown_.

Comment: ["What did you see, Nyan Lights? ***What did you see?!***"](https://xkcd.com/979/)